# JButton dosen't generate random string from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, random, jframe, jbutton

I want a new `String` from my `Array` to show in console every time I press the button in `JFrame`. 
However, when i press the button in `JFrame` it only show me 1 String that dosen't change.

Here is my code:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton rand;
private String random;

public Start() {

    frame = new JFrame("Java Jar exec");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(450, 305);
    frame.setLocation(610, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);  

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    rand = new JButton("Rand");
    rand.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
    rand.addActionListener(this);
    rand.setActionCommand("rand");
    rand.addMouseListener(this);

    panel.add(rand);
    frame.add(panel);

    ArrayList<String>arr = new ArrayList <String>();
    arr.add("1");
    arr.add("2");
    arr.add("3");
    arr.add("4");

    random = arr.get(new Random().nextInt(arr.size()));

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String name = e.getActionCommand();

    if (name.equals("rand")) {
        System.out.print(random + '\n');
    }
}
```

There is more code, but this is the only important.

Comment: Can you post the whole method which is called when you press the button? Based on your code I think that you generate a single value when you initialize the components and then the same value is printed every time you press the button.

Comment: you need re-random on `System.out.print(random + '\n');`

Comment: how do is use re-random? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your *actionPerformed* method like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String name = e.getActionCommand();

    if (name.equals("rand")) {
        random = arr.get(new Random().nextInt(arr.size())); //generating random number should be here
        System.out.print(random + '\n');
    }
}
```

The thing is that if you put the line that generates random number within *Start()* method, *random* variable will be initialized only once but when it will be in *actionPerformed* method, assignment will be done every time you press the button.